# Graphlab SFrame constructor converting NumPy S1 dtype to int

Tags: python, numpy, graphlab

Here is an example:

```
import graphlab as gl
import numpy.random as npr    
npr.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], size = 100, replace=True).dtype
df_so = gl.SFrame({"col1": npr.randint(low = 1, high = 3, size = 100), 
               "col2": npr.randint(low = 1, high = 10, size = 100), 
               "col3": npr.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], size = 100, replace=True)})
df_so.column_types
```

I would like to understand:

- why?
- if there is a way to prevent this.

Comment: The column types I get are `[int,int,str]`, which I believe is expected. What version of graphlab are you using and what platform are you on?

Comment: @EvanSamanas Thank you for your response. I am using stock Anaconda Python 2.7.11 on Windows 8.1. I am using GL Create in a conda environment as the docs suggest, and the output of `pip freeze`is [here](https://gist.github.com/tchakravarty/189f3b3d9ece092aa3b614fb06e4280c).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to respond to this. I just tried this again on my Windows machine using GLC 1.8.5 and got the output I expected. What are the column types you get? What is the output of the block of code you posted?